# property of local Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The local Sobolev space,defined as $W^{k,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$, is the space such that for any $u \in W^{k,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ and any compact $V\subset \Omega$, $u \in W^{k,p}(V)$. I am just wondering if for any $u\in W^{k,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$, there exists ${u_n}\in C^\infty(\Omega)$, such that $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $W^{k,p}(V)$ for any compact $V\subset \Omega$

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Take a sequence of smooth cutoff functions $\eta_n$, each with compact support in $\Omega$, and such that every compact subset of $\Omega$ is contained in the set $\{\eta_n=1\}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

The function $u \eta_n$ belongs to $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, and therefore there is a function $u_n\in  C^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\|u\eta_n-u_n\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}<1/n$. The sequence  $(u_n)$ does what you want.

Comment: This should say $W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)$ to invoke the appropriate density argument? Otherwise we need locally star-shaped domain?

Comment: @HPark I guess you do not use MSE anymore, but I still wanna comment for the future readers. By Theorem 2 in the section 5.3.2. in Evans' PDE classic textbook (which is exactly the density theorem the answer quoted), the domain only needs to be bounded and open. Openness and boundedness are for constructing a sequence of nested open sets which "increasingly converge" to the original domain. Then one uses partition of unity subordinate to this sequence of open sets to conclude the proof of the density argument.