# Space of locally Sobolev functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

What is the definition of $W_{\text{loc}}^{k,p}(U)$? I found this denotation in Evans and from the context I guess, $u\in W_{\text{loc}}^{k,p}(U)$ iff
\begin{equation}
u\in W^{k,p}(V)\text{ for all }V\subset\subset U,
\end{equation}
but it would be nice to get an affirmation. Thanks!

Comment: [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616482/property-of-local-sobolev-space?rq=1) perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I could've found myself. Shall I delete my question, then?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a moderator here. You could perhaps give a good answer yourself, or a reference to a full definition of $W_{\rm loc}^{k, p}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to thread linked the definition should be
\begin{equation}
W_{\text{loc}}^{k,p}(U)=\{u:U\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}:u\in W^{k,p}(V)\text{ for all }V\subset\subset U\}.
\end{equation}